# Cannot deploy GAE + Cloud Bigtable to Managed VM

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm trying to deploy [this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/java/managed-vm-gae) to Google Cloud. I'm following the exact instructions, and got an error saying

> ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Not enough VMs ready (0/1 ready, 1 still deploying). Deployed Version: 20150723t080450.385919969320427256

When I go to cloud console -> app engine -> versions, I did see a new version deployed, but the size of the version is 0, and going to the module URL returns 503 server error even after I waited 30 minutes.

```
Error: Server Error
The service you requested is not available yet.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

I didn't modify anything in the example except the `PROJECT_ID`, `CLUSTER_UNIQUE_ID`, etc. What could be the problem here?

Comment: Someone else reported this yesterday -- looks like something changed w/ the tooling, I'll look into it and get back to you by Friday afternoon.

Comment: It should work now -- sorry about the problem.

Comment: @AidenJohnson — great to hear that we've solved your problem! Would it make sense to delete this question as it's (a) no longer reproducible and (b) not applicable to anyone else?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comment [Cannot deploy GAE + Cloud Bigtable to Managed VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31591974/cannot-deploy-gae-cloud-bigtable-to-managed-vm#comment51138955_31591974), this was a historical problem that was resolved.